# Slack icon on wingpanel

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel, apps

I've installed the official slack app (https://slack.com/downloads) but when I closed (not quitting the app) there's no icon on wingpanel.. Is there some way to have it?

Comment: I have the same problem because it's a known issue unfortunately. I contact to the support and said: "a little tricky to provide support for older Ubuntu versions right now" At the moment there is no solution for that.