# Cannot see system tray on Elementary OS Freyja 0.3.2

Tags: icons, wingpanel

I am using Slack amongst other software on Elementary. When I hit the 'x' it is supposed to minimize to the tray. When I try to do this, I cannot see any icon in the system tray. But I still get notifications, so I know that it is still running. How do I fix this, so that I can see the icon?

Comment: See this: [http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/slack-icon-on-wingpanel](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/slack-icon-on-wingpanel)

Comment: Google has most of the answers, but now all :)